I am facing a lot of compatibility issues if I have node 17+ installed and working on reactnative project with expo 52.0.9
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~9.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~52.0.9",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.3",
    "expo-router": "~4.0.9",
    "expo-secure-store": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.13",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^22.9.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "~29.7.0",
    "jest-expo": "^52.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },

I was working fine when i was in expo 51 but then got an update in expo go that it dont support 51 try updating to 52 again it came to the same cases version compatibility
